# Displaying Fetched date in a custom calendar React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

So basically i created a custom calendar for my doctor Appointement App that looks like this: [image]

it displays the current week and date of the days.
till now those time slot are a static array that i made and rendered in a flatlist:

```
this.state = {
      timeList: [
        { id: 1, time: "08:00 am" },
        { id: 2, time: "09:00 am" },
        { id: 3, time: "10:00 am" },
        { id: 4, time: "11:00 am" },
        { id: 5, time: "12:00 pm" },
        { id: 6, time: "01:00 pm" },
        { id: 7, time: "02:00 pm" },
        { id: 8, time: "03:00 pm" },
        { id: 9, time: "04:00 pm" },
        { id: 10, time: "05:00 pm" },
        { id: 11, time: "06:00 pm" },
        { id: 12, time: "07:00 pm" },
        { id: 13, time: "08:00 pm" }
      ]
    };
and:
<FlatList
            data={this.state.timeList}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderTimeData(item, index)}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
```

So my problem is i want to render the time from a fetched data in a way that take into consideration the the date of the day.for instance, here is a log of the data:

[image] 
so from that attribut "date_start" i should make sure the date is matching in my calendar so i can display that "9:30"
Any idea how can I approach it?
i hope i made my self clear enough and thank you for your suggestions

Comment: what npm library are you using for date picker?

Comment: @sv12 i'm not using any date picker

Comment: could you explain a bit more about your problem?

Comment: @SDushan so i want to replace that 8am,9am,10am...  time slot with data from my database. this db(as you can see in the log picture) contains an attribut to indicate what are the avaible time for an appmnt(date_start). but the format is like this"2020-03-22 09:30" and all i'm interessted in displaying is the last part"...9:30".knowing that the first part"2020-03-23" should determine the date to place this time slot(9:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a library like [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to identify the date & time of your object as below,

```
let date = moment("2020-03-23 09:30").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(date)

let time = moment("2020-03-23 09:30").format('h:mm A');
console.log(time)
```

For more information check [String format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) of Moment.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: @AymenAymen Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to choose date and time for a day the [official react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/datepickerandroid#__docusaurus) recommend you to use [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker#react-native-datetimepicker)

With this you will have the native component for rendering date in IOS and Android.

Comment: i already rendered the date,what i want to do is from that 'date_start' attribute that i got from fetch, extract for example ''2020-03-23" and go in my calendar to put '9:30' slot